# How can I get a translation of patents

Tags: research, translation, language, german

I'm making a research about some Patents, but i need them in German language!
How i can get the translation of the Patents?

Comment: Are they filed in the US?

Comment: yes they are, like this one ( US 6309010 B1 )

Comment: Why German? You plan to file in Germany? Did you try Google or Microsoft translation?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a machine translation of the Abstract on Espacenet:

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=6309010B1&KC=B1&FT=D

Google Translate would be my next suggestion.